# phpMyAdmin on Linux Mint 19 fresh install password issue

Tags: phpmyadmin, passwords, linux-mint

I've just installed the phpMyAdmin on my Mint 19 machine, and I am able to browse to http://localhost/phpmyadmin, of course. After that, it all goes south and I'm just plain lost.

To put it simply, I've researched myself silly, but I just don't have enough experience with a FRESH install to know what credentials I should be using. Or how to reset them. Any advice appreciated.

Again, this is simply a FRESH install. Just want to know the BASIC login info to utilize my new setup.

Answer (score 0):

When logging in through phpMyAdmin, you are using your MySQL account (phpMyAdmin doesn't have its [own user account system](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html#a-word-about-users)).

MySQL's default is username root with a blank password.

If you used the Mint packaged version, you were likely prompted for a password during the package installation.